# new rails project error Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have never had a problem starting a new app, but today I got an error that said this when I tried to run rails new murphy

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require': no     such file to load -- active_support/core_ext/object/singleton_class (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/generators.rb:6
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:10
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta2/bin/rails:30
from /usr/local/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:19
```

Comment: Looks like the 3.0 beta version of Rails is installed. As Chris Ledet mentioned you should upgrade to the latest 3.0.x version. I'd also like to recommend you make the switch to using [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/). Being able to manage individual gemsets is well worth the install time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Rails 3.0 beta. Try using to Rails 3.0.9

```
gem install rails -v3.0.9
```